# EditorFor ApplyFormatInEditMode Currency not working on Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

Very frustrated!!!!

On the initial display, the currency displays fine but when I edit the value, it is not formatting.  I setup a new Project to illustrate.

```
    public class TestViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Text Box For")]
    public decimal Cost1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Editor For")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Cost2 { get; set; }
}

@model EditorForTest.Models.TestViewModel
<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cost1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cost1, new { Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Cost1) })
<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cost2)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Cost2)
<br/>

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View(CurrentTest);
    }

    private static TestViewModel _currentTest;

    private static TestViewModel CurrentTest
    {
        get { return _currentTest ?? (_currentTest = GetNewTest()); }
        set { _currentTest = value; }
    }

    public static TestViewModel GetNewTest()
    {
        TestViewModel testViewModel = new TestViewModel();

        testViewModel.Cost1 = 1234;
        testViewModel.Cost2 = 1234;

        return testViewModel;
    }
```

It looks ok when it opens:

[image]

But when you edit it, the formatting is lost.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?????

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario works with a clean MVC4 project. You must have something else that is causing this issue, check that you don't have a decimal EditorTemplate, as this would override the default DisplayFormat.